# Fetch specific data from the variable which has HTML output

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, handlebars.js

Have rendered html output from json and template using Handlebars.js.

HTML output is stored in a variable, now i need to fetch some part of the HTML by ID.

How can i get the required data.?

eg: HTML content assigned to variable

```
<ol id="maincontent">
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test1</li>
        <li>test2</li>
    </ol>
<ol id="content">
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test1</li>
        <li>test2</li>
    </ol>
```

Now i need only id="content" data.

Comment: This is a poor quality question. Please think about rewording it to make it easily understandable and state exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Whats the purpose of getting that particular data? If its only for display purpos we can do some work around

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming that you can use jQuery) Perhaps the following is what you are looking for :

```
var myVar = '<ol id="maincontent">\
  <li>test</li>\
  <li>test1</li>\
  <li>test2</li>\
  </ol>\
  <ol id="content">\
  <li>test3</li>\
  <li>test4</li>\
  <li>test5</li>\
  </ol>';
alert($("<div>" + myVar + "</div>").children("#content").html());
```

The last line calls $ (i.e. jQuery) with an HTML string to create a DOM object (cf. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2), and filters its children according to the id that you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks **lmsteffan**. This is what i was looking out for. @ others, sorry for my poor quality of sentencing. Henceforth, will post my questions in better way. Thanks Again..